# How can I link to a specific comment in a Trello card?

Tags: trello

As the activity on a card grows, specific comments can sometimes get lost in the clutter. Can I link to a specific comment?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to link to just an activity record inside a card.

The best way to keep a comment visible and near the top is to add the comment to the card description in addition to the activity records.

You can link to a card by using the link found in the "Show Card ID" button on the back of the card.